# How to make a dynamically growing data chart in Chart.JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js

I am trying to develop a *Crash Game*, where a `multiplier (Y)` increases exponentially and dynamically over `time (X)`, causing the chart to re-render at each `tick`.

You can see an [example of the chart game here](https://www.bustabit.com/play)

TL;DR: I am trying to achieve a ***"zoom-out"*** effect of the chart as my ticks increase in values (x,y).

Where **my code fails** is when ticks data values (*x,y*, respectively `time` and `multiplier`) surpass `suggestedMax` tick values. The only reason I am using `suggestedMax` is to have some labels on the chart at the beginning.

I have tried to achieve this by using both `line` and `scatter` chart type, but the final outcome is simply unacceptable from a performance point of view.

Here is my code:

```
const HomePlaygroundView = () => {
  var chart = undefined;
  const chartText = useRef(null);
  let last_tick_received = 0;
  const incrementChart = () => {
    last_tick_received += 100;
  };

  const onServerTickReceived = (multiplier, msLapsed) => {
    // Update chart multiplied

    if (chart.data.datasets[0].data.length >= 100) {
      // Halve the array to save performance (lol)

      for (let i = 1; i < 100; i += 2) {
        console.log("Reducing chart data");
        chart.data.datasets[0].data.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }

    chart.data.datasets[0].data.push({
      x: msLapsed,
      y: multiplier,
    });
    // This is basically my zoom out effect implementation...
    if (multiplier >= 2.5) { // Increase suggestedMax only if bigger data needs to be fit
      chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.suggestedMax = multiplier;
    }
    if (msLapsed > 9000) { // Same logic as above
      chart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.suggestedMax = msLapsed;
    }

    if (msLapsed < 10000) {
      // Fit msLapsed in the pre-existing 10 seconds labels of x axis (this is a hell of a workaround)
      let willInsertAtIndex = undefined;
      for (let i = 0; i < chart.data.labels.length; i++) {
        let current = chart.data.labels;
        if (current < msLapsed) {
          // Insert at i + 1? Check the next index if it's bigger than msLapsed
          let nextVal = chart.data.labels[i + 1];
          if (nextVal) {
            if (nextVal > msLapsed) {
              willInsertAtIndex = i + 1;
              break;
            }
          } else {
            willInsertAtIndex = i + 1;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      if (willInsertAtIndex) {
        chart.data.labels.splice(willInsertAtIndex, 0, msLapsed);
      }
    } else {
      chart.data.labels.push(msLapsed);
    }

    // Decimate data every so and so

    chartText.current.innerText = `${multiplier}x`;
    // Re-render canvas
    chart.update();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("rendered chart");
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    ctx.height = "350px";
    chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      // The type of chart we want to create
      type: "scatter",

      // The data for our dataset
      data: {
        labels: [...Array(11).keys()].map((s) => s * 1000),
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "testt",
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
            borderColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
            borderWidth: 10,
            showLine: true,
            borderJoinStyle: "round",
            borderCapStyle: "round",
            data: [
              {
                y: 1,
                x: 0,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
        animation: {
          duration: 0,
        },
        responsiveAnimationDuration: 100, // animation duration after a resize
      },

      // Configuration options go here
      options: {
        spanGaps: true,
        events: [],
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        legend: {
          display: false,
        },
        elements: {
          point: {
            radius: 0,
          },
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [
            {
              type: "linear",
              ticks: {
                callback: function (value, index, values) {
                  let s = Math.round(value / 1000);

                  return s.toString() + "s";

                  //return value;
                },
                autoSkipPadding: 100,
                autoSkip: true,
                suggestedMax: 10000,
                stepSize: 100,
                min: 0,
              },
            },
          ],
          yAxes: [
            {
              ticks: {
                // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                callback: function (value, index, values) {
                  return Math.round(value).toString() + "x"; // Display steps by 0,5
                },
                min: 1,
                suggestedMax: 2.5,
                stepSize: 0.01,
                autoSkip: true,
                autoSkipPadding: 150,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    });

    let lastTick = 1.0;

    let dateStart = new Date().getTime();

    setTimeout(() => {
      chartText.current.innerText = "Go!";
      setTimeout(() => {
        setInterval(() => {
          let timePassed = new Date().getTime() - dateStart;
          //console.log(timePassed);
          let calculateTick = Math.pow(
            1.01,
            0.00530133800509 * timePassed
          ).toFixed(2);
          console.log(timePassed);
          onServerTickReceived(calculateTick, timePassed);
        }, 50);
      }, 1000);
    }, 2000);
  });

  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.canvasContainer}>
      <span ref={chartText} className={classes.canvasText}>
        Ready...?
      </span>
      <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePlaygroundView;
```